# Need a hint to solve an integral...

Tags: calculus, integration

Tried solving this with few approches (u'v, ln, arctan), Still this this roots are hard to deal with and even when trying to change with t it's hard... Need a hint...

$$\int\frac{-4x^3+2x^{3/2}+5x^2-4x+\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}}{x^2+1}dx$$

Comment: I've edited your question to insert the integral typed in MathJax. Please try to do it yourself next time. What did you "change with $t$"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=t^2$ and all the radicals will disappear. $$ \int\frac{-4x^3+2x^{3/2}+5x^2-4x+\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}}{x^2+1}dx$$ transforms into $$\int\frac{-4t^6+2t^{3}+5t^4-4t^2+\frac{2}{t}}{t^4+1}2tdt $$Long division implies $$ \frac{-4t^6+2t^{3}+5t^4-4{t^2}+\frac{2}{t}}{t^4+1}2t=-8t^3+10t+4-\frac {5t}{t^4+1} $$ From here on is a piece of cake.

Comment: You forgot the factor 2 at the end and, if I'm not mistaken, there's no $8t^3$ in the last fraction.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it again.

Comment: You are correct. I will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Set $\,t=\sqrt x$, $\,2t\,\mathrm d t=\mathrm d x$. You'll fall on the integral of a rational function
$$2\int\frac{-4t^7+5t^5+2t^4-4t^2+2}{t^4+1}\,\mathrm dt=2\int(-4t^3+5t+2)\,\mathrm dt-10\int\frac{t}{t^4+1}\,\mathrm dt, $$
then decompose $\,\dfrac t{t^4+1}$ into partial fractions.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can simplify it a lot in the first place:

$$\int \frac{-4x^3+2x^{3/2}+5x^2-4x+2x^{-1/2}}{1+x^2}dx = \int \left (-4x+2x^{-1/2}+5- \frac{5}{1+x^2}\right )dx$$ $$ = -4[\frac{x^2}{2}]+2[2\sqrt{x}]+5[x]-5[\arctan(x)].$$

Comment: click on "edited" to see how I formatted the math